# Where can I find the range of IP addresses of my container OpenVZ

Tags: iptables, ip, nat, openvz, proxmox

I'm looking for the "range of IP addresses of my container"...
Where can I find those ?

/etc/network/interfaces ?

ifconfig ?

I don't know and I can't find any answers...
I need it for [this](https://openvz.org/Using_NAT_for_container_with_private_IPs) tutorial

thanks,

Comment: please explain, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Talk with your provider.

Comment: I would like to follow the tutorial I linked. In other terms, give access to internet to my container.

Comment: Ok,  the link for you: http:/openvz.org/Common_Networking_HOWTOs

Comment: The range you was looking for corresponds to private addesses you are assining to conatainer(s). If your host forwards only container's traffic you can skip It and use the above Venet example.

Comment: Thx for the link. Really simple but not working. I'll dig to find smth I would have done before which can prevent this for working. My VE is pinging my host but not internet...